# can't play video form url in video view android

Tags: java, android, video, android-videoview

I am trying to play a video from my own local server in the video view. I am giving it the url of my server.

```
http://admin:admin@192.168.0.3:8732/cam4/ERecordings/4_UNIVIEW_192.168.1.13/01-07-2020/14-39-23.mp4
```

I can access this link in any browser and play the video but my app can't play it.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       final VideoView videoView = findViewById(R.id.videoplayer);
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Buffering please wait!!");
        progressDialog.show();
       // Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://archive.org/download/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet_512kb.mp4");
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://admin:admin@192.168.0.3:8732/cam4/ERecordings/4_UNIVIEW_192.168.1.13/01-07-2020/14-39-23.mp4");
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
        //videoView.setVideoPath("http://playready.directtaps.net/smoothstreaming/ISMAAACHE/Taxi3_AACHE.mp4");
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start();
        try{
            videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(this,"can not play ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

}
```

permissions: To test I have given all permission to the app.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Error:

```
W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open http://admin:admin@192.168.0.3:8732/cam4/ERecordings/4_UNIVIEW_192.168.1.13/01-07-2020/14-39-23.mp4: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://admin:admin@192.168.0.3:8732/cam4/ERecordings/4_UNIVIEW_192.168.1.13/01-07-2020/14-39-23.mp4
```

I can access it from any browser even in mobile. Even Vlc and Mx player android app can play it. If I am putting any private server address then it is playing just fine. I am on same wifi network.

Update: I added permission android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in my android manifest but now I am getting error

```
E/MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -2147483648)
E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)
D/VideoView: Error: 1,-2147483648
```

Update 2:- I put my video file in IIS server and this time it works fine. But in my main program I am using the apache server. Earlier I was using the Libvlc android integration and it was able to play video but the same url can not be played by videoview android. The below url is working fine.

```
String url = "http://192.168.0.4/a1.ts";
```

Comment: Try to add this property in your Manifest android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" into the application.

Comment: I have done that now I am getting error E/MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -2147483648)
E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)

Comment: You are connect same network where this local video uploaded?

Comment: Because this video into your local server

Comment: yes, I am on the same wifi to which my laptop is connected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will work for you,

```
try {
        val link = "https://www.radiantmediaplayer.com/media/bbb-360p.mp4"
        val videoView = findViewById(R.id.videoview) as VideoView
        val mediaController = MediaController(this)
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView)
        val progressDialog = ProgressDialog(this)
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading video please wait!!!")
        progressDialog.show()
        val video = Uri.parse(link)
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController)
        videoView.setVideoURI(video)
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start()
        try {
            videoView.setOnPreparedListener(object : MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {
                override fun onPrepared(mp: MediaPlayer) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss()
                }
            })
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "can not play ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }


    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error loading video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

Permissions in AndroidManifest.xml.file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Thank you I have updated some information you can check that.

Comment: videoView.requestFocus();
is remaining now its working fine

Comment: I have already put this statement in the code and still it's not working. I have added a second update please look at it maybe you can help.

Comment: I can share url also

Comment: Video Url : https://www.radiantmediaplayer.com/media/bbb-360p.mp4

Comment: This URL is working because it's present on a public server. I am trying to play file from my local server apparently there is some problem with fetching file from private server.